# How to keep IntentService runnig when display is off?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, intentservice

I'm developing a simple app using `android sdk 8`.

In my app I've implemented an intent service as below:

```
public class NotificationService extends IntentService {

    public NotificationService() {
        super("NotificationService");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        while (true) {
            /// Send http request to server
            /// notify if new messages received
            SystemClock.sleep(1000);
        }
    }

}
```

It works perfectly while display is on, but when the phone sleeps this service won't do perfectly.

I'm struggling this issue entire the day. In some tutorials said we can use BroadcastReceiver and PowerManager to keep cpu awake but I can not find the solution!

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You must prevent phone from sleeping - use WAKELOCK https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html#cpu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `PowerManager` to acquire a `WakeLock` (the following example uses a field `PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock`)

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

this.wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyWakeLock");
this.wakeLock.acquire();
```

You can release the `WakeLock` this way:

```
this.wakeLock.release();
```

You can call these methods when the service is created/started or destroyed/stopped, for example.

Don't forget to add the `WAKE_LOCK` permission to your application manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```